# NSString return won't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My code won't work and I don't know why

**the following works:**

```
NSString *  words (void) {


    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You sent %d words\n", 1];

}
```

**but this won't work:**

```
NSString *  words (void) {

    return  [[[NSString alloc] stringWithFormat:@"You have %d words\n", 1] autorelease];

}
```

What's wrong, when I'm releasing it, then it wont work. Help me please.

Comment: Please elaborate on the nature of "doesn't work".

Comment: I'd be surprised if build and analyze doesn't complain about that already...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `stringWithFormat:` to `initWithFormat:`.

`stringWithFormat:` is a *class method* so it is called when the `NSString` class itself is the receiver. `initWithString:` is an *instance method* so it is called when you have an `NSString` *instance* as the receiver, like what is returned from `[NSString alloc]`.

Comment: Thanks"! how could i forget!!

Comment: +1 for the explanation, going accept you answer, but it says i have to wait 12 min before doing so

Comment: my friend, why wont this work: const char *convert = [[[NSString alloc] chat stringValue] UTF8String]; ?

Comment: @user1341993: Just do `[[chat stringValue] UTF8String]`

Comment: i know but i also plan on releasing it, when i do     [chat release]; it wont do .. it exit

Comment: The result of `UTF8String` will work after `chat` is released, but it you don't own the string because `UTF8String` is essentially just shorthand for `[[chat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] bytes]`. Since you don't own the result of `dataUsingEncoding:` then you have no control over when the bytes will be released. What you need to do is hold a reference to the data object. `NSData *data = [[chat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] copy]; const char *convert = [data bytes];`. When you no longer want the bytes, use `[data release]; convert = NULL;`

Comment: im getting : warning: 'NSTextField' may not respond to '-dataUsingEncoding:'  when i use :  NSData *data = [[chat dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] copy];

Comment: @user1341993: Oh, sorry, my mistake, I meant `[[[chat stringValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] copy];`

Comment: the :  const char *convert = [data bytes]; now says:  error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'const char*'

Comment: @user1341993: Are you compiling is Objective-C++ (i.e. does your file have `.mm` extension? Just put a cast in there, e.g. `(const char *)[data bytes]`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10761/discussion-between-dreamlax-and-user1341993)